# mvn clean reading home directory starting with "?"

Tags: xml, docker, maven, permissions, settings

I have a maven image build using following docker file.Assume 311 is user 'a'.

```
FROM maven:3.3.9-jdk-8    
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh / 
COPY ./settings.xml /root/.m2/ 
COPY ./settings.xml /home/a/.m2/ 

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
    
    USER root
    
    RUN chown 311:309 $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
    RUN chown -R  311:309 $JAVA_HOME RUN chown -R  311:309 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts
    RUN chown -R  311:309 /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
    
    RUN openssl s_client -showcerts -connect mydomain.com </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -text >mydomain.cert
    
    RUN $JAVA_HOME/jre/bin/keytool -v -alias artifactory_cert -import
    -file ./mydomain.cert -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt
    
    USER 311 ~
```

Now I am trying to do build a maven project using this image. If I invoke my docker image as a root user, then the things work fine and maven is able to read settings.xml from /root/.m2 ,which is created by docker image.And following are logs when i run as root user:

> [DEBUG] Reading user settings from /root/.m2/settings.xml

Things work fine here. But the problem comes, then i run as user 311,which is non-root user (a).
It give authentication issues and i think it is not able to read settings.xml for credentials.
It tried to read from following path:

> [DEBUG] Reading user settings from ?/.m2/settings.xml

But i would have expected

> /home/a/ instead of ?/

Any idea what this

> ?

means and I feel it is reason behind all this.How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The users in the Docker container are distinct from the users on the host. If you want to use user IDs from the host in the container, you have to add `--userns=host` to the `docker run` command parameters.

Please check [Docker's documentation on user namespaces](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/) for further details.